# Overloading with argument types that are base and inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I have something like this:

```
class BaseArg { }
class DerivedArg : BaseArg { }

interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class A : IDoSomething
{
    public BaseArg Value { get; set; }

    public A(BaseArg value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static A Create(BaseArg arg)
    {
        return new A(arg);
    }

    public static B Create(DerivedArg arg)
    {
        return new B(arg);
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

class B : A
{
    public DerivedArg DerivedValue { get; set; }

    public B(DerivedArg value)
        : base(value)
    {
        this.DerivedValue = value;
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // does something different from A.DoSomething()
        // uses additional stuff in DerivedArg
    }
}
```

However, even when I do this:

```
DerivedArg arg = new DerivedArg();
A a = A.Create(arg);
```

`A.Create(BaseArg arg)` is called (and thus `A` is created, which was not the intention).

Am I missing something here? If so, how should I rewrite this without using weird stuff such as conditions on `arg as DerivedArg`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. With the code you've given (fixed to make `A.DoSomething` virtual), the code you've given at the bottom *does* call `A.Create(DerivedArg)`. Please show a short but complete program which actually demonstrates what you're claiming.

Answer (score 2):

The correct factory method is getting executed. Set a breakpoint inside of:

```
    public static B Create(DerivedArg arg)
    {
        return new B(arg); /* set breakpoint */
    }
```

It ***appears to you*** that it isn't being executed since you've defined the local variable of type `A`:

```
A a = A.Create(arg);
```

`public static B Create(DerivedArg arg)` is being called properly and an instance of type `B` is being returned and boxed as type `A`.

Comment: No, I stepped into it and `A.Create(BaseArg arg)` is called.